# Multivariable Matching in Google Sheets - scanning for multiple values simultaneously and posting shared data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, google-sheets

I have two sheets from two different sources (Facebook Ads and Google Ads) and I want to match their data onto a third sheet. The data itself is different, but the identifiers are the same - campaign name, adset name, ad name, & date. Both sheets also have other data such as purchases & pageview data. The reason I'm doing this is because Facebook and Google report numbers differently, and I would like to compare their reporting.

Essentially, I want to scan through a row on my Facebook datasheet and grab the three names and one date. I then want to scan through every row in my Google datasheet until I find a row with the exact match for the three names & date. I then want to grab these three names, the date, the pageview data from FB, the pageview data from Google, and post this data onto a row in a third separate "comparison" sheet.

I tried VLOOKUP, but VLOOKUP forces you to pick one value as the key value. This won't work for me because I need multiple values to match across two different sheets. So I was wondering how to go about doing this.

Comment: Please try to solve your problem yourself. If you can’t get it, describe you problem better (e.g., show some simple sample data) and tell us what you tried.

Comment: The problem with this question is no effort is shown. The specification of what the original poster would like to do is here, but this site is not about coding requests from scratch. That is what a free coding service is for. This site helps people who help themselves: Show your work and if you get stuck at some place, please point out where you are stuck and this community might be able to help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. You tagged both Excel AND Google Sheets - why? Which do you  want? You refer to `VLOOKUP`, another/better option would be a `QUERY` - have you tried this approach?